# searching for python substring without regex

Tags: python

I want to search for a substring within a string between 2 delimiters '+' and '!' with '+' at the beginning of the substring. so far I have:

```
if s.find("+")> -1 and s.find("!") > -1 and (s.find("+")>s.find("!")):
    .... do this ....
```

Is there a more pythonic way to write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the strings don't overlap, you can slice the string like this

```
s = "Welcome to !+SO!"
try:
    print s[s.index("+"):s.rindex("!")+1]
    # +SO!
except ValueError:
    print "Either + or ! not found in the string"
```

Comment: Thanks, I;m going to use a variant of this - Bill

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be close to what you are searching for...the magic of the index function:

```
>>> s = 'This is an amazing + string with some delimiters ! in the middle of it'
>>> 
>>> s.index('with', s.index('+'), s.index('!'))
28
>>> s.index('**', s.index('+'), s.index('!'))                                        
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

A simple boolean response can be determined by instead using the `in` keyword:

```
>>> '**' in s[s.index('+')+1:s.index('!')]
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just split the string:

```
In [7]: s.split('+')[-1].split('!')[0] if '+' in s and '!' in s else ''
Out[7]: 'lkwej'

In [8]: s = 'aaaaaa+bbbb!ccccccc+dddddd!eee'

In [9]: s.split('+')[-1].split('!')[0] if '+' in s and '!' in s else ''
Out[9]: 'dddddd'
```

Of course, it is easy to get very sophisticated depending on how sophisticated you want things to get :). If this is for fun, you can go ahead and experiment with list comprehensions etc...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use:

```
s = 'something + string you want ! somethin else'
if all(x in s for x in ['+', '!']) \
and abs(s.index('+') < s.index('!')) > 1:
    result = s[s.index('+')+1:s.index('!')]
```

this would result only if string has delimiters and there is something between them.

and result would be:

```
' string you want '
```